# AWS GetBucketLocationRequest with UseSignatureVersion4 option

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to request a bucket location with UseSignatureVersion4 global option? In fact, I need to create an instance of AmazonS3Client with a specified region endpoint. But, for example, if I have a bucket located in "*us-west-2*" region and create a default client AmazonS3Client with "*us-east-1*" region option, I get "**The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-west-2'" error**". But I do not know a bucket location in advance.

```
AWSConfigs.S3Config.UseSignatureVersion4 = true;
string location;

using (var tmpS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessInfo.AccessKey, accessInfo.SecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
{
  var bucketLocationRequest = new GetBucketLocationRequest
  {
    BucketName = config.BucketName
  };
  GetBucketLocationResponse bucketLocationResponse = tmpS3Client.GetBucketLocation(bucketLocationRequest);
  location = bucketLocationResponse.Location.Value;
}
```